# Custom authentication in windows azure

Tags: authentication, azure

When I look at the azure mobile services:

```
Microsoft Account
Facebook login
Twitter login
Google login
Windows Azure Active Directory
```

They are all there. But sometimes user do not have an account at google/MS etc... They just want to register a custom account.

How can I do that with a single page app hosted on azure?

Comment: You can use your WAAD tenant for this. See [this related question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208212/use-windows-azure-active-directory-to-register-new-users-for-mvc-4-website)

Comment: @Nathan The custom auth in windows azure mobil service is not yet done see here: http://feedback.windowsazure.com/forums/216254-mobile-services/suggestions/3313778-custom-user-auth This is what I actually need not WAAD Whatever that is...

Comment: Working example shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25347421/implement-custom-authentication-in-windows-azure-mobile-services/25347422